# SkipCash: Unable to post payment request BytePositionInLine1

Tags: php, laravel

I was trying to use the SkipCash as my payment gateway however when I try to post the payment, It returns and an error and not sure where this coming from.

So, here is how my code structured

```
 $formData = [
            "uid" => Str::uuid()->toString(),
            "keyId" => $skipCashKeyId,
            "amount" => number_format($order->total_amount, 2),
            "firstName" => $order->user->first_name,
            "lastName" => $order->user->last_name,
            "phone" => $order->user->phone_number,
            "email" => $order->user->email,
            "street" => "CA",
            "city" => "TempCity",
            "state" => "00",
            "country" => "00",
            "postCode" => "01238",
            "transactionId" => $order->reference_no,
            "orderId" => $order->id
        ];

        $query = http_build_query($formData, "", ",");

        $signature = hash_hmac('sha256', json_encode($query), $skipCashSecretKey);

        $headers = [
            'Authorization: ' . base64_encode($signature),
            'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8',
            'x-client-id: ' . $skipCashClientId
        ];
        

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $skipCashUrl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $formData);

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $data = json_decode($response);
```

but the response is this:

```
"data": {
        "$": [
            "'-' is invalid within a number, immediately after a sign character ('+' or '-'). Expected a digit ('0'-'9'). Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1."
        ]
    },
```

I'm not sure if the issue is in the SkipCash API or something but their docs is kind of incomplete, so maybe some has experience on SkipCash, how do you format your payload and Authorization.

Thanks

Comment: Can you paste the data dump from form data in the question? `dd($formData);`

Comment: Can you link to the documentation that you're working off of here?

Comment: here is the data dump: ` ^ array:14 [ "uid" => "adf76761-fc05-4b8c-b0b2-4db99728dbf5" "keyId" => "00cf399c-443c-4435-9a99-81c27a4d8f89" "amount" => "1,300.00" "firstName" => "Ore o" "lastName" => "Bond" "phone" => null "email" => "rcena.msi@mailinator.com" "street" => "CA" "city" => "TempCity" "state" => "00" "country" => "00" "postalCode" => "01238" "transactionId" => "34599043" "orderId" => 9 ] ` - I am not very sure why it ask for a number when it clears that It accept string in docs

Comment: $skipCashUrl can you send me the URL. I am trying used this URL "https://skipcashtest.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/payments" in the postman of post method but I am getting bad request error

Answer (score 0):

I already fix this one.

The issue here is the fields is not properly align to the requirement. The way I did something like this

```
 // the key should me capitalize and the fields should not be empty
 $formData = [
            "Uid" => Str::uuid()->toString(),
            "KeyId" => $skipCashKeyId,
            "Amount" => "$order->total_amount",
            "FirstName" => $order->user->first_name,
            "LastName" => $order->user->last_name,
            "Phone" => $order->user->phone_number,
            "Email" => $order->user->email,
            "Street" => "CA",
            "City" => "TempCity",
            "State" => "00",
            "Country" => "00",
            "PostalCode" => "01238",
            "TransactionId" => $order->reference_no,
        ];
```